# R : Couldn't resolve host name

Tags: r, word2vec

I try to install rword2vec :

```
library(devtools)
install_github("mukul13/rword2vec")
```

But I get this error message :

```
Error in curl::curl_fetch_disk(url, x$path, handle = handle) : 
  Couldn't resolve host name
```

Can you help me please to resolve this problem ?

Thank you

Comment: Have you confirmed that you're not having any Internet connection problems?

Comment: I don't know I work in a company, so there is many security polic here .. i don't know if is there a proxy or no..

Comment: I put my laptop in airplane mode and was able to replicate your error message. I suspect that R isn't able to access Github for some reason.

Comment: Ok, thank you for your response

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this same issue with other packages/libraries from GitHub while on a work network. I resolved the issue by switching to another internet network (e.g., my home internet). I was able to download the packages and install the packages.